# Writing a recursive function that takes an array and the size of the array as arguments, prints the array, and returns nothing

Tags: arrays, c

I'm very new to programming (since August) and recursion is my Achilles heel. The question is this: Write a recursive function `printArray()` that takes an array and the size of the array as arguments, prints the array, and returns nothing. The function should stop processing and return when it receives an array of size zero.

So the function alone would be something like this?:

```
void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE) {
 
  int counter = 0;

  if (SIZE == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (SIZE > 0) {
      printf("%d", arr[counter]);
      counter++;
      printArray(arr, SIZE - 1);
  }
  puts("");
}
```

I'm honestly grasping at straws here so excuse the facepalms I may cause as I am looking at countless of codes and trying to piece some of them together and see if it can help me in any way.
And when implementing it into `main()`, should I initialize additional variables? Mainly a new array seeing as anything I place in `arr[]` within the function parameter is out of scope.

Comment: You say "return nothing" but then have `return -1`?

Comment: *"So the function alone would be something like this?"* - Yeah..., [something like that](https://pastebin.com/ykukj7kj).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions take a bit of thinking though to trace the program execution-path as the recursive calls *"wind-in"*, and then *"unwinds"* after the recursion is broken and each recursive function call completes. For example take the simple case of:

```
void prnarray (int *arr, int nelem)
{
    if (--nelem > 0)                    /* wind-in (twice) until nelem == 0 */
        prnarray (arr, nelem);
    
    printf ("%d\n", arr[nelem]);        /* unwind outputting elements */
}
```

(where `nelem` is the number-of-elements in the array, technically not its "size" [unless it is an array of `char`])

Trace what happens if that function was called with:

```
int main (void) {
    
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 },
        nelem = sizeof arr/sizeof *arr;
    
    prnarray (arr, nelem);
}
```

The easiest way is just make a table with the value of `nelem`. For example:

**Winding-In**

- `nelem == 3`:

initial call from `main()`

```
    prnarray (arr, nelem);
```

then in the first function call, `--nelem` reduces the value of `nelem` by `1` before being evaluated by the `if()`.

- `nelem == 2`:

following the `if()` statement, the execution path is:

```
    if (--nelem > 0)                    /* wind-in (twice) until nelem == 0 */
        prnarray (arr, nelem);
```

- `nelem == 1`:

then in the next call after `--nelem`, `nelem == 1`:

```
    if (--nelem > 0)                    /* wind-in (twice) until nelem == 0 */
        prnarray (arr, nelem);
```

- `nelem == 0`

then in the next call, the last recursive call, the base case is hit because after `--nelem`, `nelem == 0` so the test condition fails and the execution-path continues with:

```
    printf ("%d\n", arr[nelem]);        /* unwind outputting elements */
```

(the first element '1' is printed here)

**Unwinding**

*What happens now?? We have reached the end of the function??*

Execution will pick up after the function call that lead to this point. *Where is that?* The function call that lead to this point is the recursive call to `prnarray()` that lead to us being in the body of this function.

(under the hood each function call saves the base-pointer address on the function stack so when the function execution is done it knows where to resume execution in the calling function.)

- `nelem == 1`

So when execution of the function where `nelem == 0` ends, we pick up where we left off in the function call where `nelem == 1` -- which is returning from the prior call to `prnarray()` If we look at the whole function where `nelem == 1` (`nelem == 2` on function entry) we pick up after the previous call to `prnarray()` one-level up in the recusrion:

```
void prnarray (int *arr, int nelem)
{
    if (--nelem > 0)                    /* wind-in (twice) until nelem == 0 */
+<----- prnarray (arr, nelem);
|   
+-->printf ("%d\n", arr[nelem]);        /* unwind outputting elements */
}
```

(the second element with value `2` is printed here)

So after the prior `prnarray()` unwinds, the only command left in the execution-path is `printf()` and the second element `2` is printed and the function ends and unwinds again with the same result:

- `nelem == 2`

(`3` on entry into the function) the execution-path is the `printf()` function

```
    printf ("%d\n", arr[nelem]);        /* unwind outputting elements */
```

(the third and final element with value `3` is printed here)

- `nelem == 3`

was the original function call from `main()`, so now unwinding is complete and program execution picks up in `main()` after the call to:

```
    prnarray (arr, nelem);
```

and the program ends....

Thinking through the recursive function program execution-path and making a table is a good way to become comfortable with recursive function calls. (even if you are comfortable with them, when you get to functions making two or more recursive calls within the body of the function -- you will be right back to making a table and tracing the execution path). The branches in the program execution-path with multiple recursive calls to separate recursive functions will seem to expand with exponential complexity.

With this information, you should now be able to tweak your function and know where to look for the result to take place. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution

- `counter` is local to a function and has no effect on recursive call hence only first element of the array is printed all the time.
- on `SIZE` zero you are returning `-1` which is a compilation error.

Try to pass the address of the first index of the array something like below,

```
void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE) 
{
   if (SIZE > 0) {
       printf("%d ", arr[0]);
       printArray(&arr[1], SIZE - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could redesign the same function as (notice comments):

```
// Signature -- array      size      parameterized counter
void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE, int counter) {
    if (SIZE == 0)
        // Quitting from the function instead of returning to a void function
        return;

    // Will print arr[0] on first recursion
    printf("%d\n", arr[counter]);
    counter++;

    // Will re-execute and print counter++ (if it was 0, then 1, then 2, ...)
    printArray(arr, SIZE - 1, counter);
}
```